# Excel - Find cell containing nth occurrence of data

Tags: excel

I have a set of data in Excel that looks similar to this:

```
24/01/2020      25/01/2020      26/01/2020      27/01/2020
Item A          Item A          Item B          Item C
Item B          Item C          Item C          Item D
Item C                          Item D
```

I can run a formula to ascertain how many times a certain item occurs in the dataRange: `=COUNTIF(dataRange,"Item C")`

What I am now looking to do is get the date associated with each nth occurrence. Everything I have found online only deals with finding the nth occurrence in a single column, whereas I would like a formula that would tell me that the cell for each occurence in the full range. E.G. 1st occurrence of 'Item C' is in cell A4, and the 2nd occurrence is B3, the third is C3 and the 4th is in cell D2.

Thank you all!

Comment: If this is in conjunction with your previous (deleted) question. I feel that you would want this done through VBA. If that is the case, you could want to use `Range.Find` and `FindNext`.

Comment: This is indeed in conjunction. I wasn't sure the best protocol (I know that the last item was very ambiguous and needed a more rounded question). Thank you very much. I'll read the information regarding Range.Find and FindNext

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JvdV for the assistance with this. Using the Microsoft Docs I was able to find a combination of `Range.Find` and `FindNext`, resulting in the following:

```
Sub cellAddresses()

    With Range("A1:D6")

        Set c = .Find("Item A", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                MsgBox c.Address
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

This returns the cell addresses for each occurrence and ensures that once all occurences have been looped through, no further information is fed back.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `Worksheet Change Event`:

Import the Item_Code in Cell G1

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then

        Dim i As Long, j As Long, Counter As Long, LastRow As Long
        Dim ItemCode As String

        Counter = 1

        With Me

            ItemCode = Target.Value

            For i = 1 To 4

                For j = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

                    If .Cells(j, i).Value = ItemCode Then

                        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                        Application.EnableEvents = False

                            .Range("I" & LastRow).Value = .Cells(1, i).Value
                            .Range("J" & LastRow).Value = Counter
                            .Range("K" & LastRow).Value = .Cells(j, i).Address

                        Application.EnableEvents = True

                        Counter = Counter + 1

                    End If


                Next j

            Next i

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

[image]